# How can I encrypt Angularjs values in codeigniter?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt angularjs values using codeigniter encryption library?
Here is my code

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data">
  <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('users/details/'.$this->encrypt->encode("{{row.userid}}")); ?>">{{row.fullname}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Now, I want to encrypt `userid`. How is that possible?

**In my Users.php**

```
public function details($id) {
  echo $this->encrypt->decode($id) // the result is {{row.id}}
}
```

I want to get the real value of {{row.id}} which is 10

How can I do that? Any help? thanks :)

Comment: did you get any output?

Comment: yes, the result is {{row.id}}, It seems that {{row.id}} is converted to strings not a value in angularjs

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: nope, no error.

Answer (score 0):

you can set cookie in javascript:

```
document.cookie='userId='+userId;
```

and get in codeigniter:

```
get_cookie(''); //or use $_COOKIE["userId"]
```

then the value is in your hand to encrypte